# enable powermail spamshied is not working

Tags: typo3, powermail

I am working with powermail in typo3 version 8.7.31 and powermail version 6.1.0.

I want to enable powermail spamshield to the contact form but it not working see my code of typoscript.

I created new template for extension for contact page.
For constant

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.spamshield.enable = 1
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.spamshield._enable = 1
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.spamshield.methods.4._enable = 1
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.spamshield.factor = 75
```

Also i added in setup the same code as above but nothing happen when i entered same value to the all fields.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that the spamshield does not work?

Comment: What i think is if I add same values in all fields then it should display error massage of spam detected. Am i right?

Comment: methods.4 is a session check. methods.5 is the unique check. https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Documentation/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/SpamPrevention.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spamshield is enabled by default in powermail. So no configuration needed. What if you enter "Viagra" in all fields. Is spamshield really not working?

Comment: Hey if i add "Viagra" it's working!!! I don't know what is happening but in same form if I add "test" or "someDummyWord" then form is submitted. I don't understand. any idea?

Comment: It sounds like this is not enough spam. The unique check has (in shipping state) an `indicator=2`. If all other checks are ok, this one failed check is not enough, to categorize it as spam. But of course, you can increase `indication` to a higher value.